# How do sites like facebook hide the password details when the url does not start with https?

Tags: facebook, https

The facebook home page (http://www.facebook.com/) has an login form on it.
It does not redirect me to the https version of the same page.  I can submit the form, and it will login me in.  I have turned JavaScript off (I am using Firefox), and I don't believe they are using a frame (not that I can imagine how that would help without javascript).

If I was to make a page like this (without https), and I used fiddler to look at the data being posted, I would see the password information was being sent as plain text.

However, when I tried the same thing with facebook, it does not show me anything at all (the text tab in fiddler is blank).

I take it they have encrypted the data in some why.  How are they doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the site you are viewing is not HTTPS, when you click the login button it does a post to https://www.facebook.com/login.php, which is an HTTPS site, thus the data is secured when sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not know that, but I should have.

Comment: The answers here suggest it is bad practice to do so:  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/is-posting-from-http-to-https-a-bad-practice